# Pointers and array increment problems

Tags: c

I am learning Pointers for the first time from c K&R there was a question about creating your own Strcat function with the help of pointers and stumbled upon few things which i could not understand . I made use of printf statements to understand a part of what was going on but i am still couldn't grasp it completely .

Code:-

```
    void *Strcat(char *a , char *b)
{
    printf("*a =%c\n" , *a ) ;
    while ( *a != '\0' ) 
        ++a ;
    printf("*a =%c\n" , *a ) ;
    *a++ = *b++ ;
    printf("a =%s\n" , a ) ;
    printf("*b =%c\n" , *b ) ;
    while( *a++ = *b++ ) ; 

    }
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    char s[] = "Hello" ;
    char t[] = "World" ;
    Strcat( s, t) ;
    printf("s=%s\n" , s) ;
    printf("t=%s\n",t) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

PS- I realized that i created a pointer to null function , initially it was pointer to char to imitate the original library function but during testing i changed it to void to remove complexities . Sorry for that

Output :-

```
*a =H
*a =
a =World
*b =o
s=HelloWorld
t=orld
```

My shortcomings :-

```
1. a=World // 3rd output Line
```

I understand '%s' reads untill '\0' character . By using  `*a++ = *b++` I was expecting that i was just equating the value present at that memory adress(of a) with one at b but i guess there's more to it since the output is "World"

```
2. t=orld
```

I guess i somehow changed the base adress of t as well but i thought that by passing adress of the array i would just be changing the values at the given memory address but i somehow changed its base address as well

```
3. If any one could explain my concoction that Strcat has become
```

**I want to thank everyone who went through my entire long post even if you couldn't help me , it means a lot to me . So thanx for helping a fellow beginner out!!!**

Comment: There's no room in `s` to concatenate `t`, so your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: Try changing it to `char s[20] = "Hello";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with pointers directly; `man strcat`:

> The strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string,
>
> overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and then adds a terminating null byte.
>
> The strings may not overlap, and the **dest string must have enough
> space** for  the  result.
>
> *If  dest  is not large enough, program
> behavior is unpredictable; buffer overruns are a favorite avenue for
> attacking secure programs.*

```
while ( *a != '\0' ) 
    ++a ;
```

This fast-forwards the pointer `a` to the end of the string which is in this case also the end of the allocated memory. Any further increment and access will give UB. But this is not `strcat`'s problem: it is the caller's responsability.

With an additional string:

```
char t[] = "World" ;
char x[] = "uuuuuuuuuu" ;
char s[] = "Hello" ;
```

you see the confusion:

```
*a =H
*a =
a =uuuuuuuuuu 
*b =o
s=HelloWorld
t=World
x=orld
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a string as:

```
char str[] = "World";
```

The length of `str` will be `6` (its characters plus the null terminating character).

If you try to add values after it using pointers, what you're doing is accessing invalid memory, because that memory doesn't belong to your string; because you created your string with `6` bytes, it can put it anywhere in memory, hence, the other memory might belong to something important that you may not change.

What you could've done is created your first string with a specified length:

```
char s[11] = "Hello";
```

Because `HelloWorld\0` is `11` bytes wide, you can create an array of chars with `11` bytes.

Now you may be wondering: "What if I wanted to work with generic length strings?"

Then, you'd have to use dynamic memory for that.

EDIT:

To answer your question:

> I understand '%s' reads untill '\0' character . By using *a++ = *b++ I was expecting that i was just equating the value present at that memory adress(of a) with one at b but i guess there's more to it since the output is "World"

The output is just `World` because once you tried to change it, it didn't let you, because its memory was invalid (as explained earlier). Because of that, the string remained the same as it started.